# have any method to speed up int list to enum

Tags: python, numpy, enums

I want transform a int list to enum list, only can use for loop now, have any method faster?

only method I know:
c = [TestEnum(x) for x in b]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import numpy as np
import enum

class TestEnum(enum.IntEnum):
    a = 0,
    b = 1,
    c = 2,
    d = 3,
    e = 4,
    f = 5,
    g = 6,
    h = 7,

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = [1, 3, 5, 7]
    a = [2, 4, 6, 0]
    c = [TestEnum(x) for x in b]
    print(c)
```

any method faster, i try to numpy.But it only contain interger,not contain class enum

only 9 enums, but list(like b in sample) has 200000+ size

Comment: `map(TestEnum, b)` may be slightly faster, but fundamentally you'll simply need to loop, which won't be going *significantly* faster…

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: How many distinct enums do you have? How many values will you be converting? It's hard to see what part of this task needs to be sped up without more details-- it should not be slowing things down.

Comment: The commas (`,`) after the values should not be there -- it causes the enum value to be `(0, )` instead of `0`.

Comment: @alexis only nine enums, but list(like b in sample) has 200000+ size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `b` is already a numpy array:

```
class Enum9(enum.IntEnum):
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = range(9)

B = np.random.randint(0,9,250000)

np.array([*Enum9],object)[b]
# array([<Enum9.b: 1>, <Enum9.c: 2>, <Enum9.f: 5>, ..., <Enum9.c: 2>,
#        <Enum9.i: 8>, <Enum9.d: 3>], dtype=obje 

timeit(lambda:np.array([*Enum9],object)[B],number=10)
# 0.013394596986472607
```

If `b` is a list it's not worth it converting to array:

```
b = B.tolist()

# this implicitly converts b to array
timeit(lambda:np.array([*Enum9],object)[b],number=10)
# 0.1795911630615592
```

Better:

```
from operator import itemgetter

(b or ()) and itemgetter(*b)([*Enum9])
# <very long output>

timeit(lambda:(b or ()) and itemgetter(*b)([*Enum9]),number=10)
# 0.046161029022186995
```

Comment: Need to ensure the array "b"  is not empty，otherwise will get "TypeError: itemgetter expected 1 arguments, got 0".

Comment: @Guan Good catch. Updated post.

Answer (score 0):

You did not list any clues on how is time impacting you. Of course transforming a few ints will be fast enough with the list comprehension. By far what will take most time there is creating (or retrieving) an Enum isntance.

Without making any benchmarks it is safe to say this could take long comparing to have a pure integer list, *and* that whatever method to convert then eagerly to enums will take time.

Having a list subclass that will convert its contents to enums when the numbers are requested might be faster - and it could be something as simple as

```py
import enum

class TestEnum(enum.IntEnum):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    c = 2
    d = 3
    e = 4
    f = 5
    g = 6
    h = 7


def enumlist_factory(enum_cls):
    class EnumList(list):

        def __getitem__(self, index):
            values = super().__getitem__(index)
            if isinstance(index, slice):
                return [enum_cls(v)for v in values]
            return enum_cls(values)

    return EnumList

enum_list = enumlist_factory(TestEnum)(original_list)
```

This might be a very good path if you are not consuming all values in the list as enums - otherwise, although it won't cost you the startup conversion time, it will consume the same amount of time across execution.

Anther approach, but tha would require some benchmarking, is to use an explicit
mapping dictionary to retrieve the enum instances, instead of relying  on the 
Enum internal mechanism for that:

```py
A = TestEnum
fast_map = {getattr(A, m).value: getattr(A, m) for m in A.__members__}
my_list = [fast_map[v] for v in original_list]
```